# Injected DLL using GDI+ causes Notepad to crash

Tags: c++, crash, gdi+, hook

I have a Visual Studio solution which consists of a DLL and an EXE. My program sets a global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook. The hook procedure is defined by the DLL. I have verified that the DLL gets properly injected into all the processes I am interested in. The DLL exports a few procedures, which are defined in a header file, not in a DEF file. The EXE automatically loads the DLL and calls a method in the DLL to set the hook. When the DLL is loaded, `DllMain` sets an internal `HMODULE` variable which contains the DLL's module handle. When the EXE calls the `installHook` procedure, the DLL sets the hook. All this works fine.

When my hook procedure receives a `WM_SIZING` message, it executes another internal procedure, which is supposed to use GDI+ to draw something on the window's client `DC`. Using standard GDI works. However, GDI+ (which I need to use) does not work: the `Graphics::Graphics(HDC)` constructor causes the any program to crash as soon as I try to resize the window. Here is a snippet of the code that causes the crash:

```
void myFaultyProcedure(HWND hWnd) {
    RECT wndRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd,&wndRect);
    unsigned int wndWidth=wndRect.right-wndRect.left;
    unsigned int wndHeight=wndRect.bottom-wndRect.top;
    HDC hDc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken,&gdiplusStartupInput,NULL);
    hDc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    Graphics graphics(hDc); // I think that this causes the program to crash
    delete &graphics;
    EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd,hDc);
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

The code calculates the width and height of a given window, gets a DC, starts GDI+, creates a Graphics object, deletes the Graphics object, releases the DC, and shuts down GDI+. I cannot image why programs would crash because of these lines. Notepad and Windows Explorer both crash (The Windows Explorer window is in a separate process from the Windows Explorer Shell).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure it is the next line

```
 delete &graphics;
```

that is making your code blow up. `delete` should only be used if the pointer was obtained by `new`, here you're giving it something on the stack. Calling delete on a stack allocated variable makes no sense.

To ensure that the Graphics instance is destroyed before GdiplusShutdown is called you can introduce a new scope:

```
{
   Graphics g(...);
   g.DoStuff();
   ...
} // g is destroyed here
GdiplusShutdown(...)
```

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this, so thanks! The documentation for GDI+ says that GdiplusShutdown should be called after all the GDI+ objects have been deleted or gone out of scope. Since GdiplusShutdown is being called in the same scope as the Graphics is being created, I thought the delete operator should be used. What should I do then - will leaving it be work, and will it get automatically deallocated?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there an easy way to delete it from the stack?